# How to use a mouse in Java swing?

Tags: java, swing, programming-languages

How to do this?

I want to do this how can I do

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    switch(e.getActionCommand){

        case button1: System.out.println("button1 pressed"); 
                         break; 
        case button2: System.out.println("button2 pressed"); 
                         break;
        case button3: System.out.println("button3 pressed"); 
                        break; 
        case button4: System.out.println("button4 pressed"); 
                        break; 
        case button5: System.out.println("button5 pressed"); 
                        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `a+b;` to do??

Comment: You already are. What's the problem?

Comment: Ok... so what's the problem?

Comment: Did you mean `MouseMotionListener`, perhaps? ... is [Oracle's information](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html) not enough info?  The left side of that page has all sorts of other listener examples as well.

Comment: One can have `MouseListener`, `MouseWheelListener` or a `MouseMotionListener`. What is it you are trying to do with a "mouseActionListener" ? Here is a link to [Oracle's Java tutorials for the listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html).

Comment: What is your mouse action doing? What is it listening for?

Comment: Link to [Example - using switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Comment: What is this `e.getActionCommand` in the `switch`? Also, I don't know if a mouse has five (5) buttons. You need to be clear what you are trying to do functionally, first. What is your application doing?

Comment: Here are some points on [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: _"I am unable to write my complete code."_: Please explain what your code is for. What is it you are using the `MouseListener`'s `mousePressed(MouseEvent e)` for?

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question let's start by switch/case statement, it can be used with numbers and String in Java. So you need to deal with String when capturing the user interaction in your listener, the solution is: you need to use the method setName(...) on your Swing components and capture that name which is a String in your listener. Look at this example:

```
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
       Component c = (Component) e.getSource();
       switch(c.getName()){
         case "button1": System.out.println("button1 pressed"); 
            break; 
         case "button2": System.out.println("button2 pressed"); 
            break;
         case "button3": System.out.println("button3 pressed"); 
            break; 
         case "button4": System.out.println("button4 pressed"); 
            break; 
         case "button5": System.out.println("button5 pressed"); 
            break;
    }
}
```

But don't forget to use the method setName("buttonX") for each button when you create,because that name you passed in the method must match to one of the names in your switch/case statement.

Comment: You cannot set the button name in the constructor. There you can only set the text presented in the user interface. You must use setName(...) method to set the button's name during the construction phase. Then in the event processing you can capture in the code I provided above. Please if you enjoyed the answer press the button with the arrow up to give me some points. I did it in your question.